# ¿Como puedo iniciar el componente del carousel con materialize?

Tags: javascript, materialize

Muy buenas, la pregunta es acerca de como puedo iniciar automáticamente haciendo  pasar las imágenes de el **carousel** de **materialize** con vanilla `javascript`, el cual tengo montado según esta estructura

```
introducir el código aquí
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img 
src="img/mercado1.jpg" class="n"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img 
src="img/mercado2.jpg" class="n"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img 
src="img/mercado3.jpg" class="n"></a>
        </div>

<script>
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {
        fullWidth: true,
        indicators: true,
        shift: -1600,
        duration: 400,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que los slides inicien automaticamente podrias usar el metodo `.next()` .
Pero con precaucion, porque si el usuario esta presionando en el slide se produce un mini bug. Por lo tanto, no queremos que el slide use el metodo `.next()` cuando el usuario este clickeando sobre el slider, por eso use la propiedad `.pressed` en el if.

Las propiedades y los metodos estan disponibles en [la documentacion](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem,{
    indicators: true,
    duration: 400,
});

setInterval(()=>{
  console.log(instance.pressed);
  if(!instance.pressed){
    instance.next();
  }
},2000)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


  <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
      
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono de maravilla

Answer (score 0):

Esto sigue teniendo un bug. El problema es que el ciclo de vida del componente se maneja mal. El carousel se inicializa antes de que los elementos de la clase estén cargados (a pesar incluso de que lo inicialices con el:

```
$(document).ready({...});
```

Por tanto, Materialize no se puede aplicar las clases a los elementos que no existen y aparecen descolocados.

Al hacer un prev() o un next(), se recalculan las posiciones y se reaplican las CSS a los elementos del carousel, por lo que suele funcionar. Esperar mediante un timer para iniciar los elementos es una solución temporal, que puede daros problemas si el carousel está dentro de un elemento que tiene que tener un comportamiento como ocultarse y mostrarse.

Además, si creáis una instancia para el intervalo que ejecuta la función de inicialización y el componente en el que esté ese JS se recarga, debéis tener en cuenta que hay que limpiar ese intervalo que se está ejecutando en segundo plano, porque podríais crear un desbordamiento o la ejecución incontrolada del método varias veces seguidas.

Personalmente, en general, la resolución de este tipo de bugs por intervalos, no suele ser muy buena decisión, ya que (según el caso) podrían entrar en conflicto con el ciclo de vida de la aplicación. Si tenéis oportunidad de rastrear que el objeto está completamente cargado (lo malo es que Materialize no describe que eleve un evento en ese caso, aunque se podría hacer por JS nativo o Jquery), sería una mejor opción.